# How can you modify an http response from a j2ee filter?

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, filter, response

What is the best way to modify an http response from a servlet?  Can someone show or link some sample?

Comment: You have access to the `HttpServletResponse`. Use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this following method:

```
HttpServletResponseWrapper :

javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper
Implements HttpServletResponse interface
Use this if you want to change the Response from a Servlet

Steps to modify the Response:

1. Create a response wrapper.
         – Extend HttpServletResponseWrapper.

2. Provide a PrintWriter that buffers output.
         – Override getWriter method to return a PrintWriter that saves everything sent to it and stores that result in a field.

3. Pass that wrapper to doFilter.
         – This call is legal because HttpServletResponseWrapper implements HttpServletResponse.

4. Extract and modify the output.
         – After call to doFilter method of the FilterChain, output of the original resource is available to you through whatever mechanism you provided in Step 2. Modify or replace it as appropriate.

5. Send the modified output to the client.
         – Original resource no longer sends output to client (output is stored in your response wrapper instead). You have to send the output. So, filter needs to obtain the PrintWriter or OutputStream from original response object and pass modified output to that stream.
```

Comment: Also, the PrintWriter can modify it on the fly.  Supposed you want to remove all the 'b' or something like that, just have the write return, without writing.